# NetLogo Plot Pen Color

Tags: plot, visualization, netlogo

In plotting a certain variable for each turtle, each turtle needs to be represented by a discrete color. As written, the discrete color changes from turtle to turtle at each time step. How do I make the color assignment to a turtle permanent?

```
ask turtles [
  create-temporary-plot-pen (word who)
  set-plot-pen-color one-of base-colors
  plotxy ticks farm-size 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the colour to be maintained, you will need to store it. The easiest way is probably to have a variable for the turtles that holds its pen colour and assign that colour once only (during setup or whenever the turtle is created)